# CSS outline is different for input and input:focus

Tags: css, html

I'm having a problem with an  box and its associated css outline style. When the box is focused, it should have a blue outline (working). On form validation, if there is a problem, the .error class is added changing the outline and background color red (not working)

On focus I have a style:

```
input, select {
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: solid 1px #9598a0;
    padding: 2px;
}

input:focus{
    background: #EFF5FF;
    color: black;
    outline: solid 2px #73A6FF;
}
```

For the error:

```
input.error:focus, .error {
    outline: 2px solid red;
    background: rgb(255,240,240);
}
```

The problem is that the outline without focus is on the outside of the input box while the outline on focus is on the inside of the box so the element jumps as you click on it (CHROME).

Please see this image:

[image]

First is on focus, second is no focus with error, third is error with focus. Notice how the no focus causes the border to expand outside the object.

Is there a good way to fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify "the element jumps as you click on it?"

Comment: Mooseman, I added an image in the original post. The outline is on the inside of the element with focus, but when it loses focus, the outline jumps to the outside of the input box.

Comment: @Aaron why are you adding an outline twice to your `.error` class? I think you meant to have red border instead.

Comment: @AndresIlich Please see my reply below. I am trying to use the outline since it is supposed to not alter the size of the element (ie. going from 1px border, adding 2px outline does not cause a position shift due to size change).

Comment: @Aaron why is the outline being added twice then? once in the `.error` class and again in on the `.error:focus` event? The declaration on the main class should suffice

Comment: @AndresIlich yeah you are right. That style was combined into an input.error:focus, .error {...} group. Still doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: @Aaron exchange the outline for a 1px red border on the main class and that should suffice. Without the error class you just have a grey 1px border!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change every `outline` to `border` and give the basic `input` selector a transparent border (could be grey too for example) for it not to push the second input around et Voilá :) ([Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NoahWetjen/wHz8A/3/))

```
input{
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: solid 1px #9598a0;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 2px transparent;
}
input:focus{
    background: #EFF5FF;
    color: black;
    border: solid 2px #73A6FF;
}

input.error:focus{
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: rgb(255,240,240);
}

.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: rgb(255,240,240);
}
```

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for your comments. Looks like your example exposed one issue that seems to be the source of the problem which is a padding i'm adding to the base style. Plase see: http://jsfiddle.net/wHz8A/2/  I will also update my original post with additional details. Any ideas on resolving the alignment issue due to padding? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting [outline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset) explicitly. Any valid (see Syntax section) value should do, but for moving outline inside the element a negative one can be applied, for example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lapinek/bdLc2276/)

```
input {
    background: #EFF5FF;
    outline: solid 2px #73A6FF;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}

input.error {
    outline: 2px solid red;
    background: rgb(255,240,240);
}
```

Although you are asking about Chrome, be aware that outline-offset property is not supported in IE.